# How do I split correctly split my dataset into train, test and validation?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to split my data set into 70% training, 15% testing and 15% validation.

```
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.3, train_size=0.7,random_state=1,stratify = labels)

test_X, val_X, test_Y, val_Y = train_test_split(test_X, test_Y, test_size=0.5,
                                                    random_state=1,stratify = labels)
```

But I'm not sure if this code splits the test set into half. Also, I keep getting this error:

```
     29 def main():
     30     data, labels = load_data()
---> 31     train_X, train_Y, val_X, val_Y, test_X, test_Y = process_data(data, labels)
     32 
     33     best_model, best_k = select_knn_model(train_X, val_X, train_Y, val_Y)

/tmp/ipykernel_50/3409802801.py in process_data(data, labels)
     45     X_counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_X)
     46     X_count = vectorizer.transform(test_X)
---> 47     Xval = vectorizer.transform(Val_X)
     48     # Return the training, validation, and test set inputs and labels
     49 

NameError: name 'Val_X' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/train-test-validation-set-splitting-in-sklearn

Answer (score 1):

Do not split the `test` set into half for the second `train_test_split`. Instead first split your whole data into `train` and `test` set. Then split the `train` set into `train` and `validation` sets as shown below.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 
    = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

 X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val 
    = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) # 0.25 x 0.8 = 0.2
```

Regarding the error, you have defined `val_X` in your second split but you are using `Val_X` when using the vectorizer. Just correct the uppercase into lowercase and you should be fine!

Comment: I think all ML flow are like this, prepare original data-->prepare train data, prepare test data..
 After that experiments, building models, fitting models should be conducted on train data not on test data, hence it is good practice to create validation data from train data. Next, try to evaluate your model on test data.  However note that validation data is required if you want to avoid overfitting, improve performance, or break model fitting between epochs, .  For more details refer  , https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/train-test-validation-set-splitting-in-sklearn