# Split dataframe to a train and test sets with a cross validation of x%

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe and need to split it into a training set and test set, with 90% for Cross-Validation training, and 10% for a final test set. The problem is that I do not know where to specify that I need a cross validation of 90% in my `train_test_split` function.

Comment: You can simpy split the dataset into 90/10 first using `train_test_split` and then use any of the cross validation options (e.g. [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) on the 90%.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: See this link for details.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: [Train/Test/Validation Set Splitting in Sklearn](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15135/83275)